# nginx responds to all domains

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns

Someone else is using my AWS EC2 on preview.theirdomain.com, so my node server (behind nginx) shows up on google searches for mydomain.com.

I have followed the nginx pitfalls, or at least tried, but can't figure out why my server is still responding to theirdomain.com.

This stops the server from responding completelely, both to www.mydomain.com and preview.theirdomain.com. Not a good solution

When I comment out the second server `listen 443; ...` the server is fully open to www.mydomain.com and preview.theirdomain.com

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name preview.theirdomain.com;
    return 404;
}
server{
       listen 443;
       server_name preview.theirdomain.com;
       return 404;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    return 404;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    #more stuff that works
}
```

From google domains I am only forwarding www.mydomain.com, and as you can see, the server reroutes everything to ssl. On preview.theirdomain.com, the https is not working, as my certificates only work for www.mydomain.com

There are no other files in the /etc/nginx/sites-enables, and I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help over at Freenode #nginx, and the solution was to add `default_server` to my server.

```
server{
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    #more stuff that works
}
```

I'm sure there is a good reason why. Leaving it here for anyone else on the verge of breakdown.